# Google Cloud platform: installing Error with m1 macbook

Tags: macos, google-cloud-platform, apple-m1

I wanna deploy my node.js files with Google Cloud platform.
I already have Python 3.8.13
and trying to download gcp sdk.

I downloaded packages for macOS 64-bit
(arm64, Apple M1 silicon) in my Home directory.

And when i type ./google-cloud-sdk/install.sh in my Iterm.

There's a Error.

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/Schamtz/.config/gcloud/active_config'

what can i do for this Error?

Can i use gcp sdk with my m1 macbook?

Comment: This is not related to gcloud sdk! your current user does not have access to the file `active_config`. You should investigate why your user does not have this access. or if you want, you can try `chown -R $USER /Users/Schamtz/.config/gcloud` to change dir ownership. [you might need to use sudo or run the command as a superuser if your cuurent user doesn't have permission to use chown!]

Comment: Was it a permission issue or something else?

Comment: Was just permission issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with gcloud sdk! your current user does not have access to the file `active_config`.

You should investigate why your user does not have this access. or if you want, you can try

```
 chown -R $USER /Users/Schamtz/.config/gcloud
```

to change dir ownership.

---

Note: You might need to use `sudo` or run the command as a `superuser` if your current user doesn't have permission to use `chown`.